# Send to friend sends picture not product

Tags: email, magento1.9.3

Our send to a friend works fine..., but it sends a link of the products picture. Not a link to the products page. How can I change that? Obviously I would like people to click on the link they receive and direct them to the product page.

Edit:

**version 1.9.3.10**

> https://www.boekmetnaam.nl/

[image: screenshot send friend]

Comment: What version of Magento are you on? Are you using any custom theme or extensions?

Comment: Please specify your Magento version to get answers?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to check that which template is being sent for the Email to friend functionality. To check:

1. Login to admin panel and go to **System** >> **Configuration** >> **Catalog (Email to a friend)**.
2. Under **Email Templates** section, check the value of **Select Email Template**.

If the current template is other than **Send product to a friend (Default Template from Locale)**, then check the customized template with the selected name under **System** >> **Transactional Emails**.

There must be a template with the same name which was selected in the previous step.

If not, then you need to check the default email template from locale (**app/locale/{locale_Name}/template/email/product_share.html**).

In your case there may be something like **`{{var product_image}}`**

instead of **`<a href="{{var product_url}}">{{var product_name}}</a>`**

Please let me know if the solution works for you.